# How to convert a working Ubuntu 14.04 to virtual disk so that i can distribute to fellows?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on laptop. I want to convert it to virtual disk so that my fellows could also use it. I have read forums, some have listed VM Ware converter but its installation helping material is for windows, some people also mentioned that's for server only. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create an ISO image of your Ubuntu 14.04 partition from a live system and save it wherever you like. Virtualbox and VMware can both boot VMs from ISO files. You can share ISO files on Google Drive or whatever cloud-based storage solution you choose. 
I hope this helps. Please tell me if this doesn't work.